# Steam won't update

Tags: updates, steam

It keeps showing me this warning when i try to update

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sergio91pt/synaptics+clickpads/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sergio91pt/synaptics+clickpads/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those warnings have nothing to do with Steam, nor would they stop Steam from updating. They're letting you know that a PPA you have installed doesn't actually exist for your current release. You can remove it like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "ppa:sergio91pt/synaptics+clickpads"
```

Steam updates itself when you run it.

Comment: And yet doing so fixed my issue. Thank you very much, also i apologize for the inaccurate question, I'm new to Ubuntu.